# ie6 embed youtube not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, youtube

I'm having a problem with youtube embed (iframe) and ie6. I'm currently working on an old site of a client which requires it to support ie6.

The iframe works fine in IE8 above and other browser. But when I checked the page in ie6 in xp (modern.ie images running in virtualbox) it shows error: 
`"The page cannot be displayed"`. This only happens on IE6 (running another browser in the same OS - firefox - the iframe works just fine).

I've also tried the `<object>` method and it only show white page.

**Anyone knows how to make this work in IE6, or at least a reason why it doesn't work in that particular browser?**

*In case this is related: I can't access google's page and its product through IE6 (so I can't check if I can play youtube videos through its website). Maybe this is due to google dropping its support for IE8 under, but I can't find anything actually relate this two after googling for hours.*

Comment: so, you're running XP ... with no service packs at all? because XP SP2 supports IE8, so it's still XP!

Comment: I'd be surprised, if Youtube would work with IE6. IE6 was almost dead before Youtube was even born. Also Youtube has being developed during years, IE6 wasn't.

Comment: @JaromandaX : yep, since the client want it to support ie6, got no other choice but to run it with no SP... I also check on IE8 (running on 7 tho) and it's fine

Comment: @Teemu : my thoughts exactly (lol), but I'm trying to avoid having to remove content (which the client considered important to have) unless there really is no helping it...

Comment: next time you see the client, smack him over the head, tell him it's from me :p - this is like asking someone to make their model t ford competitive in a F1 grand prix :p I feel for you :)